# How to change the case of all but the last N characters of a file name

Tags: regex, perl

With Perl and `rename`, I want to change to lower case, or upper case, all except the last N characters in a file name.

For example, if N were 10 and upper case was wanted, then
`foo_1_bar_2-abcdef.txt` should become `FOO_1_BAR_2-abcdef.txt`.

I have tried things like `rename "y/a-z{.10}$/A-Z/" *`, but the `y` operator doesn't seem to want to take `{.10}`.

Comment: What do you think `{.10}` should be doing in this context? Because `y//` is character based...

Comment: I wonder what would be expected if it were a regex pattern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you're not understanding what `y///` is doing.

It's a character based substitution, and so you say 'transliterate' from a-z -> A-Z

In that context, the `{.10}` is just another set of characters to substitute (but with no matches on the left hand side.

To make clearer what's happening:

```
y/a-z{.10}$/A-Zlmnopq/;
```

On your string will make it:

```
FOO_n_BAR_2-ABCDEFmTXT
```

Because the '0' and '1' are mapping to characters.

To do what you want though, you could tackle it like this:

```
 s/(.*)(.{10})/uc ($1).$2/e;
```

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
   s/(.*)(.{10})/uc ($1).$2/e;
   print;
}

__DATA__
foo_1_bar_2-abcdef.txt
```

(You don't need an end of line anchor in the above because the `.*` regex is greedy).

This gives you output of:

```
FOO_1_BAR_2-abcdef.txt
```

Although you may find it better/neater to work on delimiter anchoring (such as `-text` as that seems to be what you're aiming to do. (I'm guessing):

```
s/(.*-)/uc ($1)/e;
```

Comment: Indeed, after having seen things like `rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` to change case and `s/foo/bar/` to do replacement; I hadn't link the two. From what I can see and understand, (.*-) means 'all chars before -', ?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the `\U` escape sequence instead of `uc` together with the *expression* mode of substitute. A forward look-ahead also removes the need to reincorporate the unchanged section of the string

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = join '', 'a' .. 'z';

$s =~ s/(.+)(?=.{10})/\U$1/;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPqrstuvwxyz
```

However, if your file names are always of the given form, i.e. you always want to uppercase the part before the hyphen, then you should do it by context rather than counting the number of characters to remain unchanged

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'foo_1_bar_2-abcdef.txt';

$s =~ s/^([^-]+)/\U$1/;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
FOO_1_BAR_2-abcdef.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `\U` is also dealing in a better way with unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Apart form the `s///` solution, this seems to be an easy job for [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) as well:

```
my $n = 10; # number of chars left untouched at the end
substr $s, 0, -$n, lc substr $s, 0, -$n;
```